# Geolocation webview

Tags: android

How can I set a static  location in webview?
It should not be changed even if the application is used from a different  location
I tried to change the proxy, but it didn't work. Are there other ways?
I'm trying to get users to use a location doesn't change
I'm trying to get users to use a location doesn't change

```
 public static class ProxySettings {

        private static final String TAG = "GAEProxy.ProxySettings";

        static final int PROXY_CHANGED = 193;

        private static Object getDeclaredField(Object obj, String name) throws SecurityException,
                NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
            Field f = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField(name);
            f.setAccessible(true);
            Object out = f.get(obj);
            // System.out.println(obj.getClass().getName() + "." + name + " = "+
            // out);
            return out;
        }

        public static Object getRequestQueue(Context ctx) throws Exception {
            Object ret = null;
            Class networkClass = Class.forName("android.webkit.Network");
            if (networkClass != null) {
                Object networkObj = invokeMethod(networkClass, "getInstance", new Object[] { ctx },
                        Context.class);
                if (networkObj != null) {ء
                    ret = getDeclaredField(networkObj, "mRequestQueue");
                }
            }
            return ret;
        }

        private static Object invokeMethod(Object object, String methodName, Object[] params,
                                           Class... types) throws Exception {
            Object out = null;
            Class c = object instanceof Class ? (Class) object : object.getClass();
            if (types != null) {
                Method method = c.getMethod(methodName, types);
                out = method.invoke(object, params);
            } else {
                Method method = c.getMethod(methodName);
                out = method.invoke(object);
            }
            // System.out.println(object.getClass().getName() + "." + methodName +
            // "() = "+ out);
            return out;
        }

        public static void resetProxy(Context ctx) throws Exception {
            Object requestQueueObject = getRequestQueue(ctx);
            if (requestQueueObject != null) {
                setDeclaredField(requestQueueObject, "mProxyHost", null);
            }
        }

        private static void setDeclaredField(Object obj, String name, Object value)
                throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException,
                IllegalAccessException {
            Field f = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField(name);
            f.setAccessible(true);
            f.set(obj, value);
        }

        /**
         * Override WebKit Proxy settings
         *
         * @param ctx
         *            Android ApplicationContext
         * @param host
         * @param port
         * @return true if Proxy was successfully set
         */
        public static boolean setProxy(Context ctx, String host, int port) {
            boolean ret = false;
            setSystemProperties(host, port);

            try {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 27) {

                    Object requestQueueObject = getRequestQueue(ctx);
                    if (requestQueueObject != null) {
                        // Create Proxy config object and set it into request Q
                        HttpHost httpHost = new HttpHost(host, port, "http;//");

                        setDeclaredField(requestQueueObject, "mProxyHost", httpHost);
                        ret = true;
                    }

                } else {
                    ret = setICSProxy(host, port);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "error setting up webkit proxying", e);
            }
            return ret;
        }

        private static boolean setICSProxy(String host, int port) throws ClassNotFoundException,
                NoSuchMethodException, IllegalArgumentException, InstantiationException,
                IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
            Class webViewCoreClass = Class.forName("android.webkit.WebViewCore");
            @SuppressLint("PrivateApi") Class proxyPropertiesClass = Class.forName("android.net.ProxyProperties");
            if (webViewCoreClass != null && proxyPropertiesClass != null) {
                Method m = webViewCoreClass.getDeclaredMethod("sendStaticMessage", Integer.TYPE,
                        Object.class);
                Constructor c = proxyPropertiesClass.getConstructor(String.class, Integer.TYPE,
                        String.class);
                m.setAccessible(true);
                c.setAccessible(true);
                Object properties = c.newInstance(host, port, null);
                m.invoke(null, PROXY_CHANGED, properties);
                return true;
            }
            return false;

        }

        private static void setSystemProperties(String host, int port) {

            System.setProperty("fe80::eead:e0ff:fe23:eaa3", host);
            System.setProperty("fe80::eead:e0ff:fe23:eaa3", port + "8080");
            System.setProperty("33.5102","36.29128");
            System.setProperty("fe80::84f6:7b62:322a:b253", host);
            System.setProperty("fe80::84f6:7b62:322a:b253", port + "8080");
```

Comment: Did not know that WebView has a location member. Please elaborate.

Comment: When you browse some sites, many ads appear, in my country the ads never appear because Google blocks ads and deals with my country
I want users to use the browser as if they are using it from my country

Comment: Impossible as location is determined by internet ip of device where browser is running on. This is not determined by the browser.

Comment: I must create a vpn or dnschanger to do that?